# Aligning text with newlines in a table cell

Tags: tables, align

I need to include a two-line verse in a table cell and need to force both lines to be aligned such that they begin at the same point (is this horizontal alignment?) In the MWE below, the cell with multi-line text that needs to be fixed is in the second row. What's the best way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|}
\hline
\textit{\textbf{sūktisaṃkhyā}} & \textit{\textbf{sūktiḥ}} & \textit{\textbf{ślokasaṃkhyā}}\\
\hline
1. & anavadyatṛṇādino mṛgānmṛgayāghāya na bhūbhṛtāṃ ghnatām & 10\\
\hline
2. & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}acirādupakarturācaredathavātmaupayikīmupakriyām |\\pṛthuritthamathāṇurastu sā na viśeṣe viduṣāmiha grahaḥ||\\\end{tabular}& 14\\
\hline
3. & vyavadhāvapi vā vidhoḥ kalāṃ mṛḍacūḍānilayāṃ na veda kaḥ & 19\\
\hline
4. & bruvate hi phalena sādhavo na tu kaṇṭhena nijopayogitām & 48 \\
\hline
5. & dhanināmitaraḥ satāṃ punarguṇavatsannidhireva sannidhiḥ & 53 \\
\hline
6. & svata eva satāṃ parārthatā grahaṇānāṃ hi yathā yathārthatā & 61 \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Use `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}`, i.e. `l` for the column instead of `c`..

Comment: or these two verses, the simplest for me would be loading the `makecell` package and coding `\makecell[l]{acirādupakarturācaredathavātmaupayikīmupakriyām |\\pṛthuritthamathāṇurastu sā na viśeṣe viduṣāmiha grahaḥ||}`.

Comment: Hi @Bernard is it possible to retain the text's alignment within the cell as center and yet force alignment of the two lines, like what `\being{center}...\end{center}` does?

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Your suggestion works. Thanks

Comment: That would be a bit morelong to code, but yes: load `eqparbox` and write each line in an  `\eqmakebox`, like this: `\eqmakebox[V][l] {acirādupakarturācaredathavātmaupayikīmupakriyām |}`, and the same for the second verse.

Comment: @linuxfan: I've finally found a simpler solution. Please SEE  if it corresponds to what you want;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution  uses `\Centerstack` from `stackengine`. I had to load geometry and modify the value of `\tabcolsep` to remove the `overfull \hbox` message: your table is too wide for the default margins. I also took the opportunity to add some vertical padding to cells with the `cellspace` paackage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|Sc|l|}
\hline
\textit{\textbf{sūktisaṃkhyā}} & \textit{\textbf{sūktiḥ}} & \textit{\textbf{ślokasaṃkhyā}}\\
\hline
1. & anavadyatṛṇādino mṛgānmṛgayāghāya na bhūbhṛtāṃ ghnatām & 10\\
\hline
2. & \Centerstack[l]{acirādupakarturācaredathavātmaupayikīmupakriyām |\\pṛthuritthamathāṇurastu sā na viśeṣe viduṣāmiha grahaḥ||}& 14\\
\hline
3. & vyavadhāvapi vā vidhoḥ kalāṃ mṛḍacūḍānilayāṃ na veda kaḥ & 19\\
\hline
4. & bruvate hi phalena sādhavo na tu kaṇṭhena nijopayogitām & 48 \\
\hline
5. & dhanināmitaraḥ satāṃ punarguṇavatsannidhireva sannidhiḥ & 53 \\
\hline
6. & svata eva satāṃ parārthatā grahaṇānāṃ hi yathā yathārthatā & 61 \\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]